# Does a larger heap size speed up ResultSet looping?

Tags: java, performance, memory, jdbc, heap-memory

Kind of a theoretical question, because the experiments that I've tried so far have proven inconclusive. My question is, if I do a standard ResultSet pull and loop like below:

```
final ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT email FROM emails");
while(rs.next()){
      //do something
}
```

Will having a larger heap size (say 1024MB instead of 512MB) make this loop finish faster?

Comment: Very unlikely. The main performance bottleneck is the database gathering the data, and the transmission of the data to your program, not the looping code.

Comment: Not directly but we can relate the Statement.setFetchSize() to the heap, higher the fetchSize more heap memory will be required and lesser calls will be made to database.

Comment: It is quite easy to just try it.. If you didn't notice a difference, then there probably is no difference.

Comment: It shouldn't have an influence, however and even though unrelated, it is important to consider the fact that `ResultSet` implements `AutoCloseable`, so starting with Java 7+ you should `try (final ResultSet rs = ...) { ... }`

Comment: Depends on the database driver. MySQL Connector/J is notorious for loading all rows into memory before you can process the result set, this might cause extra garbage collection pressure (and potential for out of memory errors).